# fatal error: 'clipboard_manager/clipboard_manager-Swift.h' file not found

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

Trying to run `flutter` on `IOS` simulator but it gives me `error`:

```
fatal error: 'clipboard_manager/clipboard_manager-Swift.h' file not found
```

I tried to run

```
rm ios/Podfile
rm ios/Podfile.lock
rm -rf ios/Pods

cd ios/ && pod update && pod install
```

But still its giving me the same error as shown above.

I also tried this answer on [Github](https://github.com/anuranBarman/ClipboardManager/issues/2#issuecomment-450542525). Still no luck.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your code editor? I've had success doing so after the above hasn't helped similar issues.

Comment: I tried your suggestion and also restart my macbook then run `flutter clean` and run `pubspec.yml` I still got the same error

Comment: That project appears to no longer be maintained. Probably because Flutter now has built in clipboard capabilities: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/Clipboard-class.html

Comment: thanks can you put your comment in the answer section and make more details so I can mark it as the best answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clipboard_manager package suffers from configuration errors related Swift settings for iOS deployment. The package is obsolete and no longer maintained as Flutter now includes clipboard functionality by via the Dart SDK, which works across iOS, Android, web and desktop.

Simply import the `Services` library and use the static methods to copy/paste.

```
import package:flutter/services.dart;

Clipboard.getData(format); // returns Future<Clipboard>

Clipboard.setData(data);
```